# A way to create the wall post when creating an album in a group with Facebook Graph API 2.10?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I used to do a POST /group-id/albums to create albums in a group. Then I would POST /album-id/comments to comment on the album. Then I would GET /group-id/feed?fields=comments, and find the id of my comment, and from that have the wall post id. You know, the post that says So and So added 3 photos to the album ...

Using the wall post id, I can delete the album, even though the Graph API does not allow deleting albums directly.

Starting today, the ability to post comments was removed through the API, except for page apps: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/07/18/graph-api-v2.10/

Is there any way now, without commenting, to get the album story to the wall?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer.

This parameter is not documented on the Group album, but it is on the User album. Set 'make_shared_album=true' in the post body. This will make a wall post for the creation of the album, and it looks like it shows up on your feed.

However, I cannot find a way to get that post_id. The post does not show up in the group's feed, oddly, though if you make a permalink to it, the permalink is part of the group. Sadly, the post_id is also not based on the album'd id, so there's no way to guess it.

Comment: I have added the `make_shared_album` param, but the album is not posted at the group feed. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @JCarlos no, I believe at this point there is intentionally no solution, and I've mostly abandoned this strategy in favor or a browser extension.